# Unauthorized restTemplate exchange with role secured endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-security, http-headers, resttemplate, bcrypt

I am trying to add spring security to my rest api and secure one of endpoints.
I added UserEntity which implements UserDetails and RoleEntity to Rest Api. They exists in database, and user has roles:

```
public class UserEntity implements UserDetails {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
@Column(name="id")
private String id;
private String name;
private String password;
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "user_roles",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
private Set<RoleEntity> roles;
```

and overrided necessary methods from UserDetails and set up them on true.

```
@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
    for (RoleEntity role : getRoles()) {
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
    }
    return authorities;
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return name;
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
```

In MyWebSecurityConfig which extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter added configuration:

```
 @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/offences", "/offences/*", "/offences/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
}
```

and It is working too. Endpoint is secured. But when I hardcoded some user (with "admin" username and password) in other app to send request:

```
public HashMap<Boolean, Object> find(FindOffenceForm findOffenceForm) {
  
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setBasicAuth("admin", "admin");

    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(httpHeaders);
    try {
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(URL_OFFENCE + "/find/" + findOffenceForm.getName(),
                HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);
        result.put(true, objectMapper.readValue(responseEntity.getBody(), new TypeReference<Set<OffenceDTO>>() {
        }));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        result.put(false, ex.getMessage());
    }
```

*I am getting 401 Unauthorized and in my api I can see message
WARN 13660 o.s.s.c.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder : Encoded password does not look like BCrypt.
While sending request in resttemaplete, should I code password for bcrypt?*

**EDIT: OK, so in my database I have not code password for bcrypt. I changed it and now I am getting 403 Forbidden.
I added to config .csrf().and().cors().disabled but nothing changed.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may see 403 status code because the method `ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer.AuthorizedUrl.hasRole(String role)` automatically adds "ROLE_" prefix to a String argument (see documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer.AuthorizedUrl.html#hasRole(java.lang.String))), so filter chain expects "ROLE_ADMIN" role name instead of just "ADMIN", that you passed to the method.
This may happen, if your `RoleEntity.getRoles()` returns role names like "ADMIN", "USER", etc. without any prefixes.

If that's the reason, and you don't want this default behavior, you have like 3 options:

1. use method `.hasAuthority(String authority)` instead, as suggested in javadoc;
2. in your overridden `getAuthorities()` method in `UserEntity` class rewrite `GrantedAuthority` creation logic.

For example, like this:

```
@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
    for (RoleEntity role : getRoles()) {
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role.getName()));
    }
    return authorities;
}
```

3. register a bean of type GrantedAuthorityDefaults without prefix, like this:

For example, like this.

```
@Bean
public GrantedAuthorityDefaults grantedAuthorityDefaults() {
    return new GrantedAuthorityDefaults("");
}
```

Comment: Yup, .hasAuthority(String authority) was a solution. Thanks :)